# General term for both clients and customers?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, terminology

Both customers and clients pay for either goods or services, but they still fall in the same "customer/client" category, as in they buy stuff from you.

What would be the proper general term for this category?

I'm asking because I need to store both under the same category, and don't want to choose between either customers or clients.

---

**Update**: Thanks to [Josh61](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/285876/146553)'s "clientele" answer.

But would there also be a singular noun for it?

As in:

- A client
- A customer
- A ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the given context, why don't you try **"buyer"**?

It's singular, it encompasses both clients and customers, and it describes a category of people who "buy stuff from you".

Comment: I thought about that as well, and it fits my context, but to me it lacks the descriptiveness of customer/client. Maybe I'm just too picky.

Answer (score 2):

You may us [clientele](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/clientele):

> - Clients collectively:
>     *an upscale clientele* (ODO)

[Clientele](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/clientele):

> - (British English) The clientele of a place or organization are its customers or clients. (Collins)

Comment: Although this seems correct (thank you), I was hoping there would be a singular noun for it, to fit my programming needs. Too bad, I guess? :)

Comment: Isn't "clientele" a pluralization of "client" ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use **consumer**.

"a consumer" can be a buyer, a client, or a customer.

> - [**consumer**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/consumer) - "a person who buys goods and services"

Answer (score 0):

**Shopper** would fit.

> *Definition*:
>
> 1. A ​person who is ​buying things from a ​shop or a ​number of ​shops,
> 2. One who visits stores in search of merchandise or bargains.

Answer (score 0):

I will go with ***expender*** (also, ***spender*** or ***disburser***).

> : someone who spends money to purchase goods or services [WordNet Farlex](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/expender)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a general term (that can also apply to sellers or vendors if needed) [counterparty](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/counterparty): An opposite party in a contract or financial transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using "[***purchaser***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/purchaser#purchaser__2)" or "buyer":

> A person who buys something; ***a buyer***

‘He said that more than £1.8bn was spent in England by public purchasers on food each year.’

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Answer (score -1):

"consumer" comes to mind.......

Comment: This post would be improved by explaining *why* you suggest this term, for example, by providing a dictionary definition or examples in the wild. I encourage you take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: No, traders and brokers and their customers don't consume the goods they deal in.